# How do I optimize my insert sql queries that contains field with no unique values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure

I have a staging table that all its fields are varchar and no unique values/ids in this table. I am transforming and inserting into another table with the correct data types but the queries runs for about 6 hours to write 15 million records. How do I optimize my insert sql queries since the fields do not contains unique values?

My code

```sql
INSERT INTO reportingTable
(      
    [activityYear]
    ,[stateCode]
    ,[countyCode]
    ,[loanAmount]
    ,[loanToValue]      
)
SELECT 
    CAST(activityYear AS INT) AS activityYear,
    CAST(stateCode AS varchar(2)) AS stateCode,
    CAST((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(countyCode) = 0 then '-99999999' else countyCode END ) AS INT) AS countyCode,
    TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST(loanAmount as float) as BIGINT) AS loanAmount,
    TRY_CAST((CASE WHEN loanToValueRatio='Exempt' THEN '-88888888' WHEN ISNUMERIC(loanToValue) = 0 THEN '-99999999' else TRY_CAST(loanToValue as FLOAT) END ) AS NUMERIC(14,2)) AS loanToValue,
FROM stagingTable
```

Sample data

| activityYear | stateCode | countryCode | loanAmount | loanToValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | NY | NA | 20000 | NA |
| 2018 | NC | 36047 | 105000 | Exempt |
| 2019 | IA | 42003 | 435000 | 10.05 |
| 2019 | PA | 36087 | 305000 | 74 |
| 2020 | CA | 6095 | 65000 | 90 |
| 2020 | MO | 12115 | 45000 | 80 |
| 2020 | NY | NA | 105000 | 65.11 |
| 2021 | NC | 36047 | 65000 | 95 |
| 2021 | IA | 42003 | 65000 | 85 |
| 2021 | IA | 19061 | 55000 | NA |
| 2021 | NY | 19153 | 225000 | 55.73 |
| 2021 | NY | 19153 | 300000 | 60 |
| 2021 | NC | 36047 | 600000 | 80 |
| 2021 | NC | 6085 | 10000 | Exempt |

Your help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: *`AS loanToValue,`* Why do you have that comma?

Comment: The lack of unique columns is irrelevant. Your INSERT is simply copying the rows from one table to another with no logic at all. Does your destination table have any triggers or constraints that use UDFs? Does it have many indexes? Are there indexed views using that table? Does your database have sufficient space pre-allocated or does it need to grow during the insert?

Comment: @Shmiel, The comma at the end of loanToValue is just a typo.

Comment: It may be more optimal to use an ETL process instead of ELT (e.g. use a tool like SSIS to scrub/transform/convert data before inserting into the staging table or insert directly into the target).

Comment: @SMor, My destination table has no trigger or constraints like PK etc

Comment: As an aside, `ISNUMERIC` is a bad function that generally should not be used. It only determines if a value is valid for *some* numeric type, not *which*, so that things like `-.`, `$` and `1d8` are all considered "numeric". Prefer `TRY_CONVERT` or simple pattern matches like `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`.

Comment: As to the performance, if `reportingTable` is a heap table, using `WITH (TABLOCK)` can get SQL Server to use a parallel bulk insert, which can be very beneficial (not sure if that works on Azure too, though). If that is not the case, you'll have to look at a proper ETL workflow, as T-SQL is not too flexible (or fast).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "SQL Server Import and Export Wizard" tool to output your data as a flat file. Then enter bulk insert in the destination table.
Another solution is to use ETL process tools in SSIS.

Comment: I am using Azure Data Factory and loading the data as is into my staging table before executing stored procedure (SP) to transform and load to my destination table. The transformation process and loading using SP is really slow

Comment: The code written above is very slow to execute. In SSIS, you can select data with a single selection without any conversion and perform conversions with available tools such as "derived column". For example for the "loanToValue" field.
This method is faster than doing all the work with one select and insert.